# HTaccess not working, what did I do wrong?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is what my htaccess file looks like

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev
RewriteRule ^novost/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ novosturl.php?category=$1&news=$2
```

Typically, my url looks like /novosturl.php?category=CATNAME&news=NEWSNAME

What I'm trying to do, is make it novost/CATNAME/NEWSNAME

My folder in htdocs is /dev, therefore I set the rewritebase to /dev

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Is this htaccess in /dev folder?

Comment: Yep, it is in the /dev folder

Comment: What is the url you are typing in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost/dev/novost/recenzije/urlartikla2

recenzije and urlartkila being category and news name (they work when directly accessed)

Comment: @Adi: I think you should use id number like localhost/dev/novost/1/3 ,,, localhost/dev/novost/{id=number}/{id2=number} like that